# Difference between Console.writeline() /trace.writeline()

Tags: console, trace

What is the difference between `Console.WriteLine()` and `Trace.WriteLine()` ?

Answer (score 20):

Look at these from the "*Debugging*" perspective.

- We started debugging using `Console.WriteLine()`
- Later we got to know it might not be good to print debugging data on console always. We might not even have a console. Then we started using `Debug.WriteLine()`, which prints my debug information on Visual Studio output window.
- Then we got to know that we shouldn't print all debug information in release mode, so we should use `Trace.WriteLine()` in release mode. In debug mode we can see outputs from both `Debug.WriteLine()` and `Trace.WriteLine()`.
- Here's a very good reference: [Usage of Trace and Debug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815788/how-to-trace-and-debug-in-visual-c)

> You can use the **Trace** and the **Debug** classes separately or together in the same application. In a Debug Solution Configuration project, both **Trace** and **Debug** output are active. The project generates output from both of these classes to all **Listener** objects. However, a Release Solution Configuration project only generates output from a **Trace** class. The Release Solution Configuration project ignores any **Debug** class method invocations."

Here are some relevant items that you might find useful:

- [Where to look for trace logs ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286180/trace-logs-location-where-to-view-them)
- [How to set Debug or Release Configurations ?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx)
- [Understanding build configurations.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN website: 
`Console.WriteLine()` writes the specified data, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream. Meanwhile, `Trace.WriteLine()` writes information about the trace to the trace listeners in the Listeners collection