# IIS run-time logging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I started a new, from scratch, MVC4 web application.

I added my two lines of code into the 'About' Controller.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD - debug");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD - trace");
```

I ran the site in VS/Express and hit the 'About' page. 
In the run-time Output (Ctrl-Alt-O)/Debug window I see my lines of code working.

Next close VS & I stand the site up in real IIS & hit the 'About' page.

Where do I go and find the diagnostic output? 
Because it isn't in the inetpub/logs or Event Viewer.

I post a much more extensive version of this question elsewhere.  I'll be deleting one of these two once I get to the bottom of this answer.

Comment: Set up a proper trace listener in the `<system.diagnostics>` section of your web.config.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trace logs location, where to view them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286180/trace-logs-location-where-to-view-them)

Comment: @Cory  I've been waiting years to find you.  That worked.

Comment: If you want a real recommendation for a logging solution, look into [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) combined with [SEQ](https://getseq.net/). Our developers are ecstatic about it. Far easier to configure than trace logging from IIS, and far more useful.

Answer (score 0):

-- web.config I tacked it onto the end/just inside the /configuration.  & as shown designated file is be created & written to in the root of the web application---

```
  <system.diagnostics>  
    <trace autoflush="false
    " indentsize="4">  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />  
        <remove name="Default" />  
      </listeners>  
    </trace>  
  </system.diagnostics>
```

---

In your code. Any of these three will log to the designated file.  ***But you HAVE to ...Trace.Flush().***  `autoflush=true` appears to not change help anything.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD ~ debug");
//System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD ~ trace");
//System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("HELLO WORLD ~ traceInfo");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Flush();
```

---